# Erro ao mostrar quantidade de registros de uma tabela

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Estou utilizando esse código:

```php
/* Select Count de Ativos */

    $tativos = "SELECT count(*) from ativos";
    $lista_ativos = mysqli_query($tativos);

    if(!$lista_ativos)
    {
        die("Erro no Banco - CONTAR ATIVIDADES PENDENTES");
    }

    /* Fim do Select Count de Ativos */
```

Afim de contar quantos registros eu tenho na minha tabela `ativos` do banco de dados, executei a `query` acima, porém a `query` ta morrendo, ou seja, no meu navegador está aparecendo a mensagem:

> Erro no Banco - CONTAR ATIVIDADES PENDENTES

Estou conectado ao banco de dados pelo sistema de sessão.

Comment: A chamada procedural de `mysqli_query` espera dois parâmetros. Você não devia estar passando o objeto de conexão com o banco também? Aliás, se isso não exibiu o erro na tela eu sugeriria você rever as configurações do seu servidor de desenvolvimento. Ambiente de desenvolvimento que esconde erro não é um bom ambiente.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Anderson. Você indica algum servidor de desenvolvimento?

Comment: Há um exemplo de `php.ini` no repositório oficial do PHP que recomenda algumas configurações: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-development. Comece estudando-as e as adaptando conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: Vou ler agora. Agradeço mais uma vez pela atenção.